# How to deploy solidity smart contract when one contract's constructor depends on another contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

The code example is https://github.com/facuspagnuolo/ethereum-spiking/tree/master/5-token-sale-contract

The related files are:

**1. contracts\MyToken.sol**

```
contract MyToken is BasicToken, Ownable {
  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000;

  function MyToken() {
    totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
  }
}
```

**2. contracts\TokenSale.sol**

```
contract TokenSale is Ownable {
  MyToken public token;
  uint256 public priceInWei;
  bool public tokenSaleClosed;

  event TokenPurchase(address buyer, address seller, uint256 price, uint256 amount);

  function TokenSale(MyToken _token, uint256 _price) public {
    if (_price < 0) return;

    token = _token;
    priceInWei = _price;
    tokenSaleClosed = false;
  }

}
```

**3. migrations\2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
const MyToken = artifacts.require("./MyToken.sol");
const TokenSale = artifacts.require("./TokenSale.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(MyToken);
  deployer.deploy(TokenSale);
};
```

when I deploy it by truffle and testrpc ($ truffle migrate), it fails as the following:

> Using network 'development'.
>
> Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
>     Deploying MyToken...
>     ... 0x289577d078c8fbc61585127ac123dbef43aa711529bf079c4fd400206c65e0de
>     MyToken: 0x33ddda65330e75e45d3d2e4e270457915883c2fc
>     Deploying TokenSale...
>   Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
>   Error: TokenSale contract constructor expected 2 arguments, received 0
>       at C:\Users\zklin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-contract\contract.js:390:1
>       at new Promise ()
>       at C:\Users\zklin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-contract\contract.js:374:1
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: Cross-linking with https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44502/how-to-deploy-solidity-smart-contract-when-one-contracts-constructor-depends-on.

Answer (score 1):

http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations#deployer

```
// Deploy A, then deploy B, passing in A's newly deployed address
deployer.deploy(A).then(function() {
  return deployer.deploy(B, A.address);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might work migrating only the second one so TokenSale and automatically it will be deployed MyToken.